# TinyMce Allow all Html tag

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMce and even though the danger of a script attack, I need to enable all html tags with the editor.

Currently, I'm use like:

```
valid_elements: "@[class],p[style],h3,h4,h5,h6,a[href|target],strong/b,"
              + "div[align],br,table,tbody,thead,tr,td,ul,ol,li,img[src]"
```

But always need to add something, I want to enable ALL HTML tags with all attributes. Is there such switch that Disables the HTML filtering?

Comment: This is a security nightmare waiting to happen... this means you will allow arbitrary HTML code into your program.  This is an XSS dream!

Comment: In my case I'm using tinyMCE on a JxBrowser instance in a desktop application, which shouldn't be affected by XSS. I do understand the risk implied, but it would be nice if there was an option to allow all tags (even <html>) as input if you're *really really* sure.

Comment: this solution also works in modx with TinyMCE Rich Text Editor. just put the ``*[*]`` in valid elements field in the mce system settings.
Put this in accepted answer as a comment please, my points are not enough.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can set

```
valid_elements : '*[*]',
```

to allow all html tags.

Comment: I am using a variant of this one: value_elements:'+*[*]', since the plus sign enables me to have tags without childrens. Like <i class="icon-ok"></i> in the context of the tinymce editor on a mezzanine/django/twitter-bootstrap combination.

Comment: @sw. you mean `valid_elements : '+*[*]',`

Comment: @LeftyX yes, sorry. It was valid_elements, no value_elements.

Comment: I added this but it still strips doctype, html and head

Comment: @3zzy: doctype, html and head are no html tags that can be used under a BODY tag and are therefor removed by tinymce. The valid_elements definition is only applyable to html elements that can exist under a BODY tag.

Comment: I moved style tags inside body and using @import but still the files are not loaded

Comment: @3zzy: how did you do that - can i show me the code you used?

Comment: Yes, style tags are being stripped with this.

Comment: how to keep `<style></style>` tag in tinyMCE because its removing the `<style>` tag

Comment: Until a better option is offered, I generate the style tags with Javascript:
`<script>// <![CDATA[ document.write('<style>#jiji{color: red;}</style>'); // ]]></script>`

Comment: still removes anchor tags with onclick (or any javascript).

Answer (score 5):

To keep style tags, use `valid_children : "+body[style]"`