# tinymce valid_element not allowing all the html elements

Tags: html, xhtml, tinymce

I would like my tinymce editor to allow all the html elements, include some nested kind.

I read the documents at tinymce: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

And also confirmed by this post on Stackoverflow: [TinyMce Allow all Html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266487/tinymce-allow-all-html-tag)

I use `valid_elements :"*[*]",` in my tinymce options:

```
$('.page-tinymce-editor').tinymce({ 
    theme: 'advanced',
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "fontsizeselect,bold,italic,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink,code,image,uploadimage,uploadattachment",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",

    width : "660px",
    height: "1200",
    body_id :"article",
    valid_elements :"*[*]",
    skin: "wp_theme",
    relative_urls: false,
    content_css: "http://" + location.host + "/assets/screen.css",
    plugins: 'uploadimage,uploadattachment'
})
```

But there's a nest condition in my html is still remove by tinymce. I have a piece of html like the following:

```
<span class="text">
<p> Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  </p>
</span>
```

which becomes this :

```
<p> Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  </p>
```

Tinymce removes the `span` outside the `p` tag. Other `span` tag are all fine. I studied the  tinymce over and over, but didn't come out any idea to fix this.

Is there way to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could not be done on tinymce side. Here is the post talking about it at Tinymce forum: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=98807#p98807

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children) setting! I guess p-tags are not defined/allowed al child noddes of spans by default.

Comment: Hi, Thariama thanks a lot! I would simply like to make tinymce allow all the combinations, I added: `valid_children : "*[*]",` still, the `span` tag is omitted. Am I doing it right?

Comment: is there a way to turn off this functionality of tinymce?

Comment: hmmm, you may try to switch the cleanup functionality off. in this case you will need to use the cleanup paramter: cleanup: false,

Comment: I hate to say that it's still not working. I add `cleanup: false,` to my call, still doesn't work...

Comment: add this: validate_children: false,

Comment: now I have these two: `valid_elements: "*[*]", validate_children: false,`, still not working, the `<span>` tag outside the `<p>` tag is still being striped...it's killing me...

Comment: I tried all three alternatives we've been talking about, in http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ none of them worked.. I just reported a bug to tinymce, I don't it's a bug or now..

Comment: you may also ask a question in the tinymce forum, there are many people around who are focused on tinymce

Answer (score -1):

Try something like `extended_valid_elements : '+span[p]',`  in addition to the `valid_children` setting discussed above.  And make sure to clear your cache entirely to make sure its not serving your old config file.

This should allow `p` to be a child of `span`

More information on that topic:
[Alan Storm on Magento TinyMCE](http://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce)
[Pixafy - Overcoming Magento's TinyMCE](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/overcoming-magentos-wysiwyg-part-2-customizing-tinymce-settings/)

I know this is an old topic but it still ranks high in the search results so hopefully it will help someone.