# How to send email with TinyMCE editor in PHP?

Tags: php, email, tinymce

I am sending email with PHP script which is working fine, but when I use TinyMCE as editor it's not properly working. When I use a tag with server file url, it's not available, in img tag image now show in email. It's delete href and src attributes from email, I check on Gmail and Yahoo email id. what should I do now?

This code works very well for HTML contents.
Here is code:-

```
   $headers   = array();
   $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
   $headers[] = "From: <$from>";
   $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
   mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Use the Absolute Path ie http://www.yoursite.com/path_to_file instead of relative path to file

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266487/tinymce-allow-all-html-tag

Comment: Sorry for delay reply, but I am using this code to send email. Here is :-   $headers   = array();
 $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
 $headers[] = "From:  $from";                                                      $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";                                        mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));