# TinyMCE - allow table cell element as a valid html

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266487/tinymce-allow-all-html-tag) which could help to add table cell as a valid html element of a body, but it doesn't help for some reason. The reason I need this is that I would like to use this particular content as a repeated data for another content, which contains `table` element.

Example of the initial content:

```
<td>{{IMAGE}}</td>
<td><span style="font-weight: bold;">{{SHORT_DESCRIPTION}}</span></td>
```

And the stripped content:

```
{{IMAGE}}<span style="font-weight: bold;">{{SHORT_DESCRIPTION}}</span>
```

What I have already tried:

```
valid_children: "+body[style], +body[td]",
valid_elements : '+*[*]'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: looks like someone on the tinymce forum was trying to do this very thing.  http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25443.  it may require you to manipulate some of the code to actually do this because tinymce is trying to maintain the HTML spec.  One thing I tried playing around with was the "protect" option and setting it equal to 

    protect: "/\<\/?(td)\>/g",

but this give a really weird value when you save the source.

Comment: one more thing. you could could always convert it to a comment and then back to a regular TD in javascript.  

   /*<!--td>{{IMAGE}}</td>
<td><span style="font-weight: bold;">{{SHORT_DESCRIPTION}}</span></td-->*/

Comment: The last comment on that post is interesting, also your second comment looks like something worth trying. Thanks, I will get back once I have tried those :)

Comment: hey, yet another possible solution, you could create a custom tag instead of using the td tag temporarily and then prior to adding it to the table change it back to td.

Comment: Would it not be okay to let each `td` have `table` around it, then remove them from the markup that TinyMCE returns?

Comment: Thanks all for comments and suggestions. I have resolved my problem -  see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After spending couple hours and digging into core of `TinyMce` realized that the problem is not `TinyMce`. The table cell element cannot be direct child of a body as of [html specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content).

So because `TinyMce` wraps content into `iframe`, which is another HTML page on the current page, the `<td>`'s are stripped out.

Instead of doing suggested steps in comments I have added another `textarea` which is loaded without wrapping it with `TinyMce`. I think doing this way is better in my case as I have multiple `textareas` on a page and don't want to affect them all by manipulating with `javascript`.